# VLAN does not exist in NXOS

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, cisco-nx-os, nx-os

This is my first time posting so my apologies if it's not quite right.

I created a VLAN in NXOS with the following configuration:

```
  interface Vlan100
  no ip redirects
  ip address 172.50.39.2/24
  ip pim sparse-mode
  hsrp 251 
    preempt 
    priority 130 forwarding-threshold lower 1 upper 130
    ip 172.20.50.1
  description *** Test ***
  no shutdown
```

For some reason however, when I look at the interface I get the following error:
"Vlan850 is down (VLAN does not exist), line protocol is down, autostate enabled"

I went in and created the with an "int vlan 850" from command, but I'm getting the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: You created an SVI, not the VLAN. You need to globally create the VLAN with the `vlan 100` command.

Comment: That did it, thanks RonMaupin, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not really creating the VLANs; you are creating the SVIs for the VLANs. If your switch isn't getting the VLAN information from elsewhere, then you need to create the VLANs. From the global configuration mode, you use the `vlan` command to do this. Once you have create the VLAN, you have some options, e.g. you can name the VLAN.

You can refer to the Cisco documentation, e.g. [*Configuring VLANs*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/5_x/nx-os/layer2/configuration/guide/Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Layer_2_Switching_Configuration_Guide_Release_5-x_chapter4.html#steps_1058746-CLI):

> ### Creating and Deleting a VLAN - CLI Version
>
> You can create or delete all VLANs except the default VLAN and those
>   VLANs that are internally allocated for use by the device.
>
> Once a VLAN is created, it is automatically in the active state.
>
> ---
>
> **Note**  When you delete a VLAN, ports associated to that VLAN become inactive. Therefore, no traffic flows and the packets are dropped. On
>   trunk ports, the port remains open and the traffic from all other
>   VLANs except the deleted VLAN continues to flow.
>
> ---
>
> If you create a range of VLANs and some of these VLANs cannot be
>   created, the software returns a message listing the failed VLANs, and
>   all the other VLANs in the specified range are created.
>
> ---
>
> **Note**  You can also create and delete VLANs in the VLAN configuration submode.
>
> ---
>
> **Before You Begin**
>
> Ensure that you are in the correct VDC (or enter the **switchto vdc**
>   command). You can repeat VLAN names and IDs in different VDCs, so you
>   must confirm that you are working in the correct VDC.
>
> SUMMARY STEPS
>
> 1. **config t**
> 2. **vlan** {*vlan-id* | *vlan-range*}
> 3. **exit**
> 4. (Optional) **show vlan**
> 5. (Optional) **copy running-config startup-config**